# Detect idle WebWorker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'd like to be able to detect when a script loaded as a web worker goes idle, meaning that there is nothing pending in the event loop -- no callbacks, active timers, etc.  If the script were run in node.js, it would be the time at which the process exits.

Comment: I can't think of (nor find) a good way to do this. Any chance you could share other details in the case there's a better workaround?

Comment: "no callbacks"... Even `self.onmessage`? What is the worker to be used for when it's not idle?